# PostgreSQL Ошибка в запросe (7): ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" LINE 4: "INN" integer(10) NOT NULL,

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Раньше, в основном, работал с MySQL, вот угораздило выбрать для Laravel тип БД PostgreSQL, теперь со старта упираюсь в ошибку, причем код этот сгенерировал сам `Adminer (Open Panel Server)`

подскажите, что не так в запросе?

```sql
CREATE TABLE "counterparty" (
  "ID" int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("ID"),
  "INN" integer(10) NOT NULL,
  "NAME" text(256) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: integer - он и есть INTEGER, к нему не нужно указание длины. Сделайте INN varchar(10) или varchar(12) если возможны физические лица. ``TEXT`` - text variable unlimited length. т.е длина не ограничена, указывать не нужно. Укажите varchar(255), если нужно.

Comment: Вот так тоже ошибка  CREATE TABLE "counterparty" (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "inn" varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  "name" varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
);

Comment: Запятая лишняя( пример [здесь](https://dbfiddle.uk/heOskwGn)

Comment: точно, спасибо вам большое, все получилось!